# Why won't angular allow me to pass parameter to function in provider's useFactory?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular5

**app.module.ts**

```
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        CoreModule,
        HelloFrameworkModule,
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: Logger,
        useFactory: loggerProviderFunc(1),

      }]
    })
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private c:Logger){ 
   }
}
```

**logger.ts**

```
export class Logger {
  constructor(private msg: string) {
     console.log(this.msg);
  } 
}
```

> Error:ERROR TypeError: factory is not a function
>       at _callFactory

I AM getting the 1 as the passed value in console but I am also getting errors just right after it. However I get zero errors in console if I just remove the parameter ie change `loggerProviderFunc(1)` to `loggerProviderFunc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `provideFactory:` field requires a function, not the result of a call to a function.

If you wish to use it with an argument you can use an arrow expression:

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    HelloFrameworkModule,
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: Logger,
    useFactory: () = > loggerProviderFunc(1),
  }]
})
```

Perhaps Angular also allows to invoke functions for `useValue:`, but this I have not tested. If this works, note that it will be called only once, whereas the factory method is invoked everytime the resolver does his resolving job.

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    HelloFrameworkModule,
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: Logger,
    useValue: loggerProviderFunc(1)
  }]
})
```

Comment: `If this works, note that it will be called only once, whereas the factory method is invoked everytime the resolver does his resolving job.` this is useful information. Thanks a ton, I now understand this.
btw useValue does work. I have tried it.

Comment: @SamuraiJack You're welcome and thanks for the feedback on `useValue`.

Comment: Is it somehow possible pass both values & services with your method ? I've tried it and have the feeling, I can use either `deps: []` for services, or your example for the value, but not the both...